# $.when promise is resolving too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, localforage

I'm wondering why $.when is resolving too early?
I need it to resolve only when all the others promises have resolved.
Am I missing something?

Update: http://jsfiddle.net/7hdx5j6z/6/

```js
  var promises = []

  localforage.iterate(function(value, key) {
    if ( key.indexOf('params_') === -1 ) {
      promises.push(localforage.removeItem(key))
      console.log(promises)
    }
  })

  $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    console.log('all done!')
  })
```

Comment: Missing semicolon. Missing semicolon. Missing semicolon. Missing semicolon. Missing semicolon. Missing semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iterate` itself returns a promise.  You need to wait on that before the `promises` array is populated.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hdx5j6z/10/)

```
var promises = []

var x = localforage.iterate(function (value, key) {
    if (key.indexOf('params_') === -1) {
        var promise = localforage.removeItem(key)
        promises.push(promise)
        console.log(promise)
    }
})

console.log("x", x);
x.then(function () {
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
        console.log('all done!')
    })
});
```